# Why am I not able to load my custom CSS?

Tags: php, wordpress

function file

```
<?php

   function test_theme(){
    wp_enqueue_style("customestyle", get_stylesheet_uri() )

   }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_theme' );
```

and I added wp_head to my header. I also have stylesheet file in my root folder.

Comment: I assume you mean `custom`, not `costume` or `custome`?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to convert my html/css design into wordpress theme.

Comment: Maybe you spelled `customestyle` wrong so it does not find the theme?

Comment: Are there any logs you can provide?

Comment: I don't think that matters

Comment: when I add wp_head to my header it seems that wordpress loads its own scripts and styles but not my own stylesheet

Comment: @Rain123456 Yes, it does. How are we supposed to help you otherwise?

Comment: are you able to visit this site? http://www.example.dev.cc/

Comment: You have to put the URI to your stylesheet.  You're just using get_stylesheet_uri() which just returns the uri of the theme's stylesheet.

Comment: what is the URI of my stylesheet? Do you mean get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Comment: @Rain123456 Well, what CSS are you trying to load.

Comment: the stylesheet that is mandatory for WordPress. The one with theme name and author name info on it.