# Unable to load custom CSS on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created an HTML/CSS design and now I'm trying to convert it to a WordPress template. I've created the stylesheet and function.php.

I have the following code in my function.php

```
<?php

   function test_theme(){
    wp_enqueue_style("customstyle", get_stylesheet_uri() )



   }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_theme' );
```

I've added this to my header.php

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

For some reason after adding that WordPress has added a few scripts and links to the header but not my custom stylesheet

What am I doing wrong? I'm also new to wordpress development and following a youtube video.

Comment: Is the name of your stylesheet `style.css`, and inside the theme's root directory?  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: yes. it's in the root folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I not able to load my custom CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235298/why-am-i-not-able-to-load-my-custom-css)

Answer (score 0):

How to create a wordpress theme from scratch:

1. Create your theme folder in the wp-content/themes/yourtheme
2. Create an index.php file in your theme folder
3. Create your stylesheet style.css in your theme folder
4. Place your code in the index.php file according to the wordpress rules

   `<?php
   get_header();
   echo "<h2>This is the index</h2>";
   get_sidebar();
   get_footer();
   ?>`
5. Place your CSS in the style.css according to the wordpress rules.  Usually we add this at the top of the style.css so that you no longer have to enqueue it in the functions.php

```css
/*
 * Theme Name: Your theme
 * Theme URI: https://yourtheme.com
 * Author: Memyself Andi
 * Author URI: https://yourtheme.com
 * Description: My WordPress theme.
 * Version: 1.0
*/
```

Now go into your wordpress install and go to Dashboard > Appearance > Themes > Activate "Your theme"

Comment: I've done all that. The styling seems to work when I add it in my index.php for example <div style=" "> but not when I use style.css

Comment: I am currently making my own theme and this is always my starting code.  It is working in wordpress v 4.9.7 without any problems.  Strip down whatever you are doing to the basics.  Then add on top of it.